# mysql get columns of foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Table Movie that has columns (Title, Category), column Category is a foreign key from table Category(CategoryID, Name). CategoryID is the one I'm getting from the Movie table because if I set the Category.Name as foreign key, i get error. Now I want to select all the movies from the Movie table but instead of getting the CategoryID, I want the Category.Name.

edit:

**Movie Table**

[image: Movie Table]

**Category Table**

[image: Category Table]

as you can see the Category column on Movie table is equal to CategoryID from the Category Table. I tried foreign key the CategoryName instead but I just get errors. Now I want a query that can get all movies (MovieName, Category(Name instead of ID)).

Comment: provide sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: question is very unclear. Also provide your effort which you have already made.

Comment: @009820  you should upvote the answer which helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select m.MovieName, c.CategoryName 
from Movie as m,Category as c
where m.Category = c.CategoryId
```

Do inform if this doesn't produce the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

Use join

```
select moviename, categoryname
from Movie m inner join Category c on c.id=a.category
```

Comment: but CategoryName is from Category table not Movie

Comment: @009820 have you tried my answer - check it - it's a join using your foreign key

Comment: unfortunately I get no result.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic inner join query:

```
select m.MovieName, c.CategoryName 
from Movie m join
     Category c
     on m.Category = c.CategoryID;
```

If you have problems with this, you should review your basic SQL understanding.